# Como realizar contagem de produtos de forma correta?

Tags: php

Preciso fazer uma contagem de produtos para mostrar na frente do subfiltro que tenho em uma página, mas por mais que tente os valores estão ficando incorretos, achei que poderia ser a forma como estou mostrando os registros, com o DO e WHILE, acabei fazendo a inversão para WHILE e DO, vejam esse exemplo, o primeiro filtro:

```
Espelho 
  c/espelho (02)
```

Vocês pode conferir aqui:
[Exemplo de Contagem:](http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=2&sub=15)

Na verdade tenho 3 produtos com espelho, mas minha contagem pega inicialmente 2, o código que mostra o filtro, subfiltro e a contagem é esse:

```
// VERIFICA SE TEM DEPARTAMENTO E SUBDEPARTAMENTO
if ($dep != ""  and $sub != "") {   

// ARRAY PARA GUARDAR VARIÁVEIS
$arrayProdutos = "";
$arrayFiltros = "";

// COMEÇANDO O MENU
while($row_rsPesquisa = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsPesquisa)) {               

    if ($arrayProdutos == "") { 
        $arrayProdutos = $row_rsPesquisa['id_produto'];                     
    } else {
        $arrayProdutos = $arrayProdutos . "," .$row_rsPesquisa['id_produto'];
        // print_r($arrayProdutos);
    }

}

    mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
    $query_filtro = "SELECT 
                          filtro.id_filtro,
                          filtro.descricao
                        FROM
                          produtos_filtro_subfiltro
                          INNER JOIN filtro ON (produtos_filtro_subfiltro.id_filtro = filtro.id_filtro)
                        WHERE
                          produtos_filtro_subfiltro.id_produto IN ($arrayProdutos)
                          GROUP BY
                          produtos_filtro_subfiltro.id_filtro";
    $filtro = mysql_query($query_filtro, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_filtro = mysql_fetch_assoc($filtro);                                           
    $totalRows_filtro = mysql_num_rows($filtro);

// MOSTRANDO MENU
do {

    $IdFiltro = $row_filtro['id_filtro'];

    echo 
      "<ul class='menu'>
        <li><a href='#'>$row_filtro[descricao]</a></li>
        <li class='current-menu-item'></li>                
      </ul>";   
    // FIM DO MENU                  

        // COMEÇANDO BUSCA DE DADOS PARA SUBMENU
        mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
        $query_rsSubFiltro = "SELECT
                              COUNT(*) AS registro,  
                              subfiltro.descricao,
                              subfiltro.id_subfiltro
                            FROM
                              produtos_filtro_subfiltro
                              INNER JOIN subfiltro ON (produtos_filtro_subfiltro.id_subfiltro = subfiltro.id_subfiltro)
                            WHERE
                              produtos_filtro_subfiltro.id_filtro = $IdFiltro AND 
                              produtos_filtro_subfiltro.id_produto IN ($arrayProdutos)
                            GROUP BY
                              subfiltro.descricao";
                              // echo $query_rsSubFiltro;
        $rsSubFiltro = mysql_query($query_rsSubFiltro, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_rsSubFiltro = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSubFiltro);
        $totalRows_rsSubFiltro = mysql_num_rows($rsSubFiltro);

        do {
            // RESGATANDO O FILTRO PARA COMPOR A URL DE BUSCA
            $somaFiltro = $row_rsSubFiltro['registro'];
            $IdSubFiltro = $row_rsSubFiltro['id_subfiltro'];
            $descProdutoSub = $row_rsSubFiltro['descricao'];
        echo 
          "<ul class='menu2'>
            <li><a href='resultado.php?dep=$dep&sub=$sub&filtro=$IdFiltro&subfiltro=$IdSubFiltro'>  $descProdutoSub ($somaFiltro)</a></li>
          </ul>";
        } while($row_rsSubFiltro = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSubFiltro));

        // FIM DO SUBMENU
} while($row_filtro = mysql_fetch_assoc($filtro)); // FIM DO WHILE DO MENU

// echo $arrayFiltros;
} // FIM DO IF
?>
```

Comment: Amigo, o seu código e seu exemplo tem falha de SQL Injection

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @IsvaldoFernandes, já concertei isso, agora o problema da contagem, ainda não.